# Use CSS For Space At Bottom of Header

Tags: html, css

I can't get any sort of a gap between the bottom of "headermenu" and the top of "list". No values for margin-bottom nor padding-bottom move the table down the slightest bit. I could probably add margin-top to the table, but because I use this header across the site I'd rather make the single fix there as opposed to a janky fix on every page. Thanks in advance!

```css
#headermenu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.tc {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headermenu">
    <div class="alignleft">Create New</div>
    <div class="alignright"><a href="?logout">Logout</a></div><br>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="alignleft">View</div>
    <div class="alignright"><a href="?edituser">Manage User Settings</a></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="alignleft"><a href="index.php">Main Menu</a></div>
    <div class="alignright"><a href="?admin">Administrator Options</a></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>


  <table border id="List" class="tc"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: This is likely caused by the `position: absolute`. Adding that takes the element out of the normal flow of the page so margin on the bottom of that element won't have an effect on the elements below it. Try changing to `position: relative` or remove that line all together if not needed.

Comment: Removed it and no change:

#headermenu{
    padding: 0 0 50px 0; /*top right bottom left*/
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 75%;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: It should have - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOdJyoz

Comment: FWIW your posted HTML is invalid/incomplete here making it more work to answer your question for others.  Consider a functioning snippet.

Comment: Turns out the browser was using a cached version of the stylesheet; forcing a refresh with Ctrl + F5 reloaded and gave the desired result. If you want to create an answer I can accept WTFranklin I'd be happy to, and thank you for your help!

Comment: FYI, floats are not a modern layout technique and shouldn't be used like this. The whole notion of clearing divs is positively archaic. Look at flexbox or inline-block styling instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: absolute` will take the element out of the normal flow of the page so any margin on this element won't affect the element below this. Using `position: relative` will put the element back in the flow of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float. Add below CSS:

```
#headermenu::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```